# C# require interface for field

Tags: c#, oop, abstract-class

I'm an objective-C / swift developer moving into C# for a project.  I'm looking for something similar to protocols.  My research has pointed me to using either an interface or abstract class, which will suit my purposes just fine.  I'm trying to plan for future developers at other locations.

My product relies heavily on MVC architecture because it needs to have a common UI while pulling from disparate databases depending on facility.  In my comfortable objective-C world, I can require a datasource object to implement a protocol and then I know anyone else who writes a new datasource object has to comply with the predefined datasource protocol.  At this point, I can expect the view and controller to more or less behave as expected with minimal changes to controller code.

Is there a C# equivalent?  Is there a way to force (or at least strongly recommend) a class field in the controller always implement an interface or inherit from an abstract class?

Comment: Using an interface will be the correct approach here. Create your interface, add the method signatures to it, then all your datasources should implement this interface.

Comment: @JohanP is there a way to force someone to use that interface?  I’m likely being overly concerned. If someone were to swap in a different data model that didn’t use the interface, will anything in the compiler give them a warning?  I’m new to C# so I may not be phrasing this well. Thank you for the prompt response.

Comment: You can have a method that accepts the interface only i.e. `void SaveToDatasource(IDatasourceProvider provider) { }` which forces you to pass in an implementation of the interface.

Comment: If your moving to a new language, best learn that language https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/,

Comment: @JohanP very interesting. I will research that more.

Comment: @JohanP that’s exactly what I needed. Would you submit as an answer so I can mark complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an interface will be the correct approach here. Create your interface, add the method signatures to it, then all your datasources should implement this interface.

```
interface IDatasourceProvider
{
    void Save();
}


class FilesystemDatasource : IDatasourceProvider
{
   void Save()
   {
      // save to disk
   }
}


class SqlServerDatasource : IDatasourceProvider
{
   void Save()
   {
      // save to sql server
   }
}
```

Then you can use DI to get the providers injected into a constructor and use that to then call `Save()`, not caring about the actual implementation. You can have a service with methods that accept an `IDatasourceProvider` where you can call `Save`. This will force calling to to pass an implementation of the interface if they want to use the method.

```
void SaveToDatasource(IDatasourceProvider provider)
{
    provider.Save();
}
```

Comment: Combining DI with the interface was the key. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Although Interface is one avenue, you can also get into classes with inheritance and polymorphism.  This way, you can have your base-class have common properties and methods with given signatures.  Make the methods "virtual" will allow you to "override" them on derived classes from this base.

This option can help prevent duplication of code too on common things like working on a List(ofThings).  You can create a virtual method of "GetThings()" and your main base-class can still cycle through and operate on them.

So there are many avenues you can go to.

From your post, you do sound pretty savvy, so you might also want to look into "generics" which is also a powerful feature too.

Interface is like a contract saying anything that uses my interface must have all the components, properties, methods you express.  This forces you to declare them all separately on each class using it.

An Abstract class is more of a class declaration of what Must be found on a class.

However, defining a class WITH code that operates on (whatever), you can derive from without repeating the code throughout.

Hope these options help you some, and if you ask with more specifics of what you are trying to do, many out here can help guide you into an approach that might be better than others.

Comment: Genetics sound promising. Thanks for the tip. I need to research that more.